# How to change chunks of data in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large `numpy` 1 dimensional array of data in Python and want entries x (500) to y (520) to be changed to equal 1. I could use a for loop but is there a neater, faster `numpy` way of doing this?

`for x in range(500,520)
    numpyArray[x] = 1.`

Here is the for loop that could be used but it seems like there could be a function in numpy that I'm missing - I'd rather not use the masked arrays that numpy offers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[]` to access a range of elements:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((10))
print(a) # Original array
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
startindex = 2
endindex = 4
a[startindex:endindex] = 0

print(a) # modified array
# [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```